# Excel formula to find value from field in list and return associated value

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to create a excel formula that search for a value in a cell in a list of different search words. When found, it shall return the value for that line.

Search word  Value:

```
Grocery     31    
Pub         42    
Restaurant  45    
Taxi        58    
Bus         58
```

I guess the pseudocode will be something like this:

```
=IF((A1 IS IN C1:C10);D1:D10;"blank")
```

I've created this formula, but it's hard to maintain. I want to use a list instead of modifying the formula.

```
=IF(OR(    (ISNUMBER(SEARCH("GROCERY", E3))), "31", 
(IF(OR(    (ISNUMBER(SEARCH("PUB", E3))), "42", 
(IF(OR(    (ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Restaurant", E3))), "45", 
(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Taxi", E3)), "58", "")))))))`
```

Comment: Consider using `VLOOKUP()`

Comment: Vlookup looks like doesn't cope very well with text fields. The search text can be "OUTLAND AS AVD OSLO 2, OSLO, NO -628,0" where in the list i have "outland". The old formula used SEARCH to find in the text. 

Is there a way to combine these functions?

Answer (score 2):

Say our text to be searched is in **A1** and our little lookup table is in **D1** through **E5**:

[image]

In **B1** enter the array formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$1:$D$5,A1)),$D$1:$D$5,"")),$D$1:$E$5,2,TRUE),"")
```

[image]

As you see, the formula scans the little table; finds *Pub* and returns the associated numeric value.

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

Answer (score 2):

INDEX/AGGREGATE will find and return the correct value:

```
=INDEX(F:F,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($E$1:$E$5)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($E$1:$E$5,A1))),1))
```

[image]

Comment: ***NICE!*** ............................I will keep this for my toolbox.

Comment: Yours will return multiple where mine only returns the first match on the list, will be interesting to see what the OP wants.  Both have their place.